# Clickable URL in .csv file displayed in HTML using PHP

Tags: php, html, excel, csv, numbers

I have a few .csv files that store car accessories for my dealership and are displayed on a webpage using PHP by logging onto a local computer I've setup as a web server. I'd now like to add a row, holding URLs that point to images for each accessory. I know you can insert a link into a cell by using =HYPERLINK("http://www.google.com") and it works while inside Excel/Numbers, but once saved as a .csv it doesn't do anything. Also wondering if the PHP code I have setup to display the .csv files may cause an issue.

If anyone has any idea on how I can insert a URL into a .csv and have a clickable URL using PHP displayed in a web browser I'd greatly appreciate it!

Here is my PHP code for those interested:

```
<?php
 echo "<html><body><table>\n\n";
 $f = fopen("csv/exterior.csv", "r");
 while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) {
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach ($line as $cell) {
            echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>\n";
  }
 fclose($f);
 echo "\n</table></body></html>";
?>
```

Comment: csv files are only for data.  If you want clickable links why not save as .xlsx instead?

Comment: I assumed web browser wouldn't be able to display .xlsx files. Am I incorrect?

Comment: I see, I was viewing this through the lens of Excel.  This will not work for you.  What you probably want to do is figure out how to put the link in with PHP. You could store the link as text in Excel, and then while looping with PHP look for some indicative character in the link and instead of displaying the text, insert a link.